# How to create federation metadata XML for “Relying Party Trust” and “Claims Provider Trusts” for ADFS 2.0 on a Mac

Tags: node.js, passport.js, adfs2.0

Hi we're wanting to integrate our web app with a clients existing ADFS Provider service. Our application will use NodeJS along with passport-saml to connect to the ADFS Provider.

However to my understanding to generate the Relying Trust Party XML we need Microsoft's wizard adfssetup.exe which only works with Windows Server.

Is there a way to create this Trust and claims XML document without a windows machine?

... obviously one could freestyle code it but i dont really trust myself.

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but did you find the answer? @Drew